# powershell passing by reference

Tags: json, powershell, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to pass a JSON by reference and then add something to it. For example, I want to get the same thing as:

`$json.commontokens.search.tokens.token += $newItem`

I keep the keys following `$json` in a list of strings in `$jsonList` (since the keys are unknown and can change) to build `$json.commontokens.search.tokens.token`:

```
    $jPath = $json
    foreach($item in $jsonList){
        $jPath = $jPath.$item
    }
```

As a result, `$jpath += $newItem` doesn't keep the change made to `$json` (but works for `$jpath`). So I thought I needed to pass by reference to keep the change. Something like

```
function adder{
   param(
      [ref]$j
      $stringList
   )
   if ($stringList -ne $null) {
      $first = $stringList.first.value
      $stringList.removefirst()
      adder ([ref]$j.value.$first) $stringList
   } else {
      return $j
   }
}

$jpath = adder ([ref]$json) $jsonList
$jpath.value += $newItem
```

Again, this works for `$jpath`, but nothing happens to `$json`. When I try `$jpath.value[70]`, I get the expected answer, but `$json[70]` doesn't exist. In fact, I tried it without the function:

```
$jpath = [ref]$json.commontokens.search.tokens.token
$jpath.value += $newItem
```

But it still doesn't work. Am I doing the referencing wrong? Or does it have something to do with the keys?

Comment: It may have something to do with your function.  I see you're creating the function "adder" and you reference "adder" inside of it.  It should give you some kind of error about not knowing what you're referencing.

Comment: When you pass arguments to a function that takes an object reference, you need to include the reference in the call, i.e. `adder -j ([ref]$Json) -stringList $List`.  There's no need to return `$j`, you need to manipulate `$j.Value` (also, pass it a valid object to begin with)

Comment: Clarification:  `return $j.Value`, `$j.Value += $first` and `$jpath += $newItem` in your example should clear this up.

Comment: `[ref]` "magic" only work with variable. `[ref]$j.value.$first` will reference **copy** of value.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't really understand it, but I managed to get it to work.
In adder, I changed the recursive line from

```
([ref]$j.value.$first)
```

to

```
([ref]$($jvalue.value.$first))
```

I also added a `return` to make it more obvious I was doing recursion.

For some reason, I still couldn't do `$jpath.value += $newItem`; However by removing `$token` from `$jpath`, `$jpath.value.token += $newItem` works.

So instead of adding all the strings from stringlist, I skipped the last one.
Adder was changed to skip the last string:

```
($stringList -ne $null)
```

was changed to

```
($stringList-ne $stringList.list.last)
```

where `$stringlist` is actually just a node now (I should probably change the name). So the final code is `$jpath.value.($stringList.Last.value) += $newItem`.

I guess I just can't straight up modify `$jpath.value`? Or something?